# PHP if else noimage

Tags: php, image

I'm basically a designer who hand codes HTML, but am a hack when it comes to PHP. I've been asked to add image icons within a product search results table on a PHP/MySQL site that has had many programmers over a decade, causing a sloppy mess of code.

I have the following code at the top of a search results page that calls out the name of the image:

```
$image2 = $row['item'] . ".jpg";
$imagefile2 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/product_images/$imagefile2";
if(file_exists($imagefile2)){
```

Within the table itself I hacked this to get the correct image to show:

```
print "<td><center><img src=/product_images/$image2 width=80><br>
```

Of course, if there is no image, there is a broken image link. I dod not know the proper syntax to tell the server that IF there is no image, THEN show `noimage.jpg` (located in same folder). This is probably a couple lines of added code at best, but after a couple hours of searches and attempts I surrender.

Comment: the missing line in the above table is "img src=/product_images/$image2"

Comment: Your `$imagefile2` line is confusing. You set `$image2` but don't use it

Comment: I would just use mod_rewrite in an htaccess in the `product_images` folder and if the file doesn't exist, rewrite it to the other image. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! -f \n RewriteRule . noimage.jpg`. Then any url that doesn't exist in that folder shows the noimage. You could even rewrite it to a php script that logs the missing file and sends out the noimage. Then you can easily see what products don't have an image or link to the wrong image to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the file exists and if it does, set the image2 variable to point to it.  If it doesn't exist, set the image2 variable to point to the "no image" image.

```
if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/product_images/".$row['item'].".jpg")){

$image2=$row['item'].".jpg";

}else{

$image2="/product_images/noimage.png";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/product_images/".$row['item'].".jpg")){
$image2=$row['item'].".jpg";
}else{
// Specify No Image File Path to Variable
$image2="/product_images/noimage.png";
}
?>

<td><center><img src="<?php echo $image2; ?>" width="80"><br>
```